# Relative path in fop xml config

Tags: java, xml, spring, apache-fop

I have a PDF export, and I'm using external conf file with link to font-file (font is used for cyrillic glyphs)

```
<font metrics-url="file:////fonts/DejaVuSerif.xml" kerning="yes" embed-url="file:////fonts/DejaVuSerif.ttf">
<font-triplet name="DejaVu Serif" style="normal" weight="normal"/></font>
```

but in this case, it causes `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /fonts/DejaVuSerif.xml`

problem is how to locate the correct path
I know a local path /usr/lib/tomcat/webapps/myProject/WEB-INF/fonts/DeJavuSerif.xml
but how to locale **relative** path, for example

```
<font metrics-url="file:///**${contextPath}**/fonts/DejaVuSerif.xml" kerning="yes" 
embed-url="file:///**${contextPath}**/fonts/DejaVuSerif.ttf">
<font-triplet name="DejaVu Serif" style="normal" weight="normal"/></font>
```

Comment: Which version of FOP are you using?

Comment: @lfurini version of FOP is 2.1

Comment: Have you seen this page from FOP's documentation about the [`ServletContextURIResolver`](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.0/servlets.html#uriresolver)? It seems to provide a way to achieve what you want, though I don't know whether it can be applied to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem referencing an image inside a `<fo:external-graphic src="path/image_to_display.jpg">` tag inside my xsl file.

According to the Fop 2.2 [documentation](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.2/configuration.html), (see the table and the footnote) the base url which is used for loading images and fonts, is defined by the location of the `fop.xconf` configuration file. For instance, if your fop.xconf and the image to display are located in the following directories (which have the same root) :

```
/WEB-INF/classes/FOP/fop.xconf
/resources/images/image_to_display.jpg
```

then, using JSF, you can load the configuration file for your fop instance with this code (omitting try-catch):

```
private FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new File(".").toURI()); 

public void yourMethod() {
    ServletContext contexteServlet = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();
    File baseDir = new File(contexteServlet.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/classes/FOP"));        
    File xconf = new File(baseDir, "fop.xconf");
    FopConfParser parser = new FopConfParser(xconf); //parsing configuration  
    FopFactoryBuilder builder = parser.getFopFactoryBuilder(); //building the factory with the user options
    FopFactory fopFactory = builder.build();
    FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
    OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, out);
```

If, inside the `fop.xconf` configuration file, you set the base url to go up three directory levels, like this

```
<base>../../../</base>
```

Then, your base directory will be at the top of your structure and you will be able to display the above mentionned image with :

```
<fo:external-graphic src="resources/images/image_to_display.jpg">
```

Since fonts are also located relative to the base directory, this solution should be applicable to your case also.